# Typing function parameters that take generics "of the same instance"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have something very similar to [this typed Event Emitter](https://rjzaworski.com/2019/10/event-emitters-in-typescript) and wanted to make a helper function that keeps types. [I put my attempt in a TS play sample](https://tsplay.dev/w61gRW), which is reproduced below.

In my sample, I only get a generic `eventName: string`, and `callback: (e: any) => void` as a result. Is there a way to tie the three arguments together to the *same* instance of these generics?

```js
import EventEmitter from 'events';

type EventMap = Record<string, any>;

type EventKey<T extends EventMap> = string & keyof T;
type EventReceiver<T> = (params: T) => void;

interface Emitter<T extends EventMap> {
  on<K extends EventKey<T>>
    (eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
  off<K extends EventKey<T>>
    (eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
  emit<K extends EventKey<T>>
    (eventName: K, params: T[K]): void;
}

export class MyEmitter<T extends EventMap> implements Emitter<T> {
  private emitter = new EventEmitter();
  on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>) {
    this.emitter.on(eventName, fn);
  }

  off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>) {
    this.emitter.off(eventName, fn);
  }

  emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, params: T[K]) {
    this.emitter.emit(eventName, params);
  }
}

function onEmit<
  T extends EventMap,
  K extends EventKey<T>
>(
  emitter: MyEmitter<T>,
  eventName: K,
  callback: EventReceiver<T[K]>,
) {
  emitter.on(eventName, callback);
}

class Foo extends MyEmitter<{ foo: number }> {}
const foo = new Foo();
foo.on('foo',
  (value) => console.log('foo was', value.toFixed(2))
  // ^?
)

onEmit(foo, 'foo',
  (value) => console.log('foo was', value.toFixed(2))
  // ^?
)
```

Comment: The `typescript-typings` tag is not appropriate here

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Types like `EventMap`, `Emitter`, `EventKey`, and `EventReceived` should either be defined or removed from the example.  And any behavior you're talking about ("I only get a generic ...") should be present in the code.  This makes it easier for people to start working on the solution instead of trying to re-create the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: Apologies for not providing a full-fledged example. Poor form for sure. I've updated the ask with a full sample. 

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `E` generic type; is there a reason you care about some *subtype* of `MyEmitter` there?  I'd just do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wzen1m) unless you can show some motivation for `E`.  If that meets your needs I could write up the answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Good question. I think `E` was just what I started with (working my args left to right). It looks like dropping `E` fixes things. 

Comment: So, should I write this up as an answer? Or is the question no longer valid and you want to delete it?

Comment: Actually that doesn't fully solve it. I forgot to add that I extend `MyEmitter`. Here is the [updated example](https://tsplay.dev/w61gRW).

Comment: If you have an updated example it should go directly in the question, since comments are ephemeral.

Comment: I'd say that your `MyEmitter<T>` type doesn't have a strong enough structural dependence on `T` to give you the inference you want (TS can't easily infer from indexed access types, see [ms/TS#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126)); this could be modified by adding some more explicit structural dependence like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8Lnpw).  Anything else you do is probably going to end up failing inference in the same way here.

Comment: No diffs, but it looks like you just added this:
`private __hint = (t: T) => t; // added this so that the structural dependence on T is stronger`
Is that all it takes? A bit wonky, but I'm not opposed to it if it does the trick.

Comment: Also, where can one learn more about how `__hint` gets TS to play right? I get what is going on, but if this is documented somewhere that would be great to see.

Comment: @jcalz it looks like your sample fixes the issue. Do you mind posting as an answer so I can pick it?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance; on mobile right now so it’s going to be a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that TypeScript isn't consistently able to infer `T` from some type assignable to `MyEmitter<T>`, because the [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) dependence of `MyEmitter<T>` on `T` is too roundabout.  The typings look like:

```
declare class MyEmitter<T extends EventMap> {   
  private emitter: EventEmitter;
  on<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
  off<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;    
  emit<K extends EventKey<T>>(eventName: K, params: T[K]): void;
}
```

If the compiler has type `Foo` and needs to calculate `MyEmitter<infer T>` from it, what it does is perform a structural comparison of `Foo` against `MyEmitter` to get candidates for `T`.  For example, it looks at the `emit` method of `Foo` and sees

```
<K extends "foo">(eventName: K, params: { foo: number; }[K]) => void
```

And, unfortunately, it is unable to infer `{foo: number}` here.  In order to do so it would have to be able to infer from [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) such as `K extends infer keyof T`, but this does not work, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#41040](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41040) (that's listed as a bug but I'm almost sure that I've seen the TS team say that inferring from those positions led to worse outcomes than not doing so.  If I find this again I'll edit that info in here).  Or it would have to be able to infer from [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) such as `(params: (infer T)[K]): void`, but such a feature was never merged, as mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126).  So the `emit` method doesn't have anything the compiler can use to help it infer `T`.  And neither do the other members of `Foo`; they have similar typings.

So the inference completely fails and the compiler falls back to the constraint, which is `EventMap`.  And you're sad.

---

Note that if the compiler is explicitly given `MyEmitter<{foo: number}>` and is asked to do `MyEmitter<infer T>`, then it will succeed.  That's because in cases where the compiler sees identical type declarations in source and target, it can perform a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) check as a shortcut, and `{foo: number}` pops out.  The fact that this is possible at all is a potential source of confusion, because it is widely documented that TypeScript's type system is structural (shape of things) and not nominal (names/declarations of things).  And this is essentially true, but if the compiler tried to perform a full structural check for all types, the performance would be abysmal.  If a nominal check fails the compiler can fallback to the structural check.  In a perfectly sound and complete type system this would be unobservable and just give a performance boost.  But TS's type system is neither fully sound nor even close to complete, so edge cases like this happen.

---

The solution here until and unless more clever inference is implemented, is to give the `MyEmitter<T>` type some more explicit structural dependence on `T`.  One way to do this is to give it a member of type `T`, but you might not have one of those sitting around.  Another way is to give it a member that's a function type where either the parameter type or the return type (or both) is of type `T`.  An identity function fits that bill nicely, so you can augment to this:

```
class MyEmitter<T extends EventMap> {
  private __hint = (t: T) => t;   
  // rest of impl is the same
}
```

You're never going to actually use this member, and so if you want you can suppress the output to JavaScript by [`declare`-ing the member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) instead:

```
class MyEmitter<T extends EventMap> {
  declare private __hint: (t: T) => T;
  // rest of impl is the same
}
```

Either way, now `MyEmitter<infer T>` can succeed via a structural check:

```
onEmit(foo, 'foo',
  (value) => console.log('foo was', value.toFixed(2))
  // ^? (parameter) value: number
)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUQG4FMB2MEmDGKpwBmUEIcA5CqhgM7kDcAUIzAJ5gqLUwCyAhmDgBeOACUUAY2gATADw0YUYGgDmAGjh80rAHxMW7TsnQwA0ilayAKnBQAPPGmk0uJ-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-G20Ma53MT2LD8V9nQRpSbkChE4SUBtOK9WZfhbzgD8Dj9lTy2hvS24QAK5oCQwYARgTKNZCWGxkymbh3DUJYky7SC0z3eZGD7FE7ygQpuSjWUdBgzdCUPXYlgkPhWVZAAjBoghHEwxxSItcMYS80KDKA6zQJ8UA0EiyMoiQghbNs2Q5FwADEIAgd5uyw9DZD6IgJMKNBvxAcjg1pfo4HpKQ0AUBTJJEUMI3EiBYyYQgJPY9JyAsiByDwlYNVZb8UDNTwdJoCAJUrVkIBUazbLgMMOXsxFSJcysYAgUTgDsFBpHSAAmIoiiVFUAD0AH4mOYEYo3SWyNBsiT7KWdInJctyWRGTzvN8-zisk4K6A0CqUEi6LYvipKUrSuAsr6rKVhPYFahKNqlJUtSoByxggA)