# Why TypeScript cannot infer base class generic type from subclass type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I don't understand why `ExtractEvents<FooEmitter>` resolves to `EventsMap` instead of `FooEvents` in the snippet below (tested with latest 4.9.3):

```
// @strict: true
type EventsMap = Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>;

declare class TypedEmitter<L extends EventsMap>
{
  on<U extends keyof L>(event: U, listener: L[U]): this;
  off<U extends keyof L>(event: U, listener: L[U]): this;
  emit<U extends keyof L>(event: U, ...args: Parameters<L[U]>): boolean;
}

type ExtractEvents<Candidate> = Candidate extends TypedEmitter<infer E>
  ? E
  : never;

type FooEvents = {
  foo: (payload: string) => void;
}

declare class FooEmitter extends TypedEmitter<FooEvents> {}

type ExtendsFooEvents<C> = C extends FooEvents ? true : false;

// `ShouldBeTrue1` resolves to `true`
type ShouldBeTrue1 = ExtendsFooEvents<ExtractEvents<TypedEmitter<FooEvents>>>;

// `ShouldBeTrue2` resolves to `false`, should resolve to `true`
type ShouldBeTrue2 = ExtendsFooEvents<ExtractEvents<FooEmitter>>;
```

[Workbench Repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/bug-workbench/?ts=4.9.3&ssl=27&ssc=66&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0Bco4FcCmBYAUNAJ4AOWoAogG5YB20kAsgIbGgC8oASlogPawATADwwENAOYAaUAAoAdAqaxxkNExqEA2gF0AlOwB8odYQMBufPgE8ANkrKI7kSKAAqJLAPIBbeNGhYsEIAMqBYAB4BNAIuVLT0zMQG+ADe+KCgvDRCAKphkbQxoADWWIS8AGagwQYyWNR0aDnSNvAwtIFowZo5emjQABZtFngZlRW5+VFFpeVVNXUNqKDNoK3tNJ3VPX3oQ5AjGVi+0JMR0y6zldW19fFN0gpySipoAApKTN5YAbCQITsDLo0AAjXi8GxYdQjAC+lgIHgokVgTGQcTo-wAwuoBPABEwAkYONjoniCWRzoUXO5SF4Tr8hPAaBVAhRkqNQAB+CjpUBoTbUWAjfBEUigABi4PR9HYoDSHIq4LQMmITEINl4TAEaFETPE+jYRkovDxsPh1kc9lAlucEql9NZlOi1I8dL8DMlvGlkCMKTheBFiPIBWdnu9QkxRNAmKmVLtXqWLm5mDIaAqTBskCwwrwIFAAAMAMoDXgYGwCABCWFcsGwAEZ86BYFhIBDqC5oLwCyn84GxcXS+WqzX67Lgxcw4mhOOUWipzTPD53YEhJP4j6DOZ4XmiyWy5Xq7WsAAmRvN1s2dvoLv59OZrD56SQPflpstttkTvdo+9hH9l8HiOJ5jiGMRrhi07Iqi0DhmGDqwJuIxAA)

Comment: Wow, that was a strong feeling of déjà vu... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73791499/2887218).  The workaround would be to add a type hint like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6L5Ym).